# PL/SQL example which i do not understand

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have PL/SQL code which i do not understand. In line 11 data is inserted into an object called `emp`. But there is no object `emp` declared in this code. Could you please explain this to me?

```
1. DECLARE
2. TYPE emp_det IS RECORD
3. (
4. EMP_NO NUMBER,
5. EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(150),
6. MANAGER NUMBER,
7. SALARY NUMBER
8. );
9. TYPE emp_det_tbl IS TABLE OF emp_det; guru99_emp_rec emp_det_tbl:= emp_det_tbl(); 
10. BEGIN
11. INSERT INTO emp (emp_no,emp_name, salary, manager) VALUES (1000,’AAA’,25000,1000);
12. INSERT INTO emp (emp_no,emp_name, salary, manager) VALUES (1001,'XXX’,10000,1000);
13. INSERT INTO emp (emp_no, emp_name, salary, manager) VALUES (1002,'YYY',15000,1000);
14. INSERT INTO emp (emp_no,emp_name,salary, manager) VALUES (1003,’ZZZ’,'7500,1000);
15. COMMIT:
16. SELECT emp no,emp_name,manager,salary BULK COLLECT INTO guru99_emp_rec
17. FROM emp;
```

Comment: No, Linux isn't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In line 11 data is inserted into an object called emp. But there is no object emp declared in this code

`EMP` is a table, most probably owned by the same user which runs this PL/SQL code. In Oracle, we usually do NOT create tables within PL/SQL. Even if you wanted to do that, `CREATE TABLE` is a DDL and you'd have to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`). Rarely, really really rarely we create any kind of objects from within PL/SQL.

Therefore, it doesn't matter that there's no `CREATE TABLE EMP` in this script. Also, you don't have to "declare" it, you can't. If the table exists, rows are inserted into it (of course, if everything is OK with data, e.g. you aren't violating any constraints, datatypes match, etc.).

Later, in line #16, you're selecting all rows (the ones that previously existed in the table - if any - as well as newly inserted ones) into a collection named `guru99_emp_rec`.